# Why doesn't this GROUP BY Mysql query work?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT time.EmpID, time.Date,
SUM(MinutesatState) AS active FROM time WHERE State = 'active'
GROUP BY time.EmpID, time.Date;
```

Above query works

```
SELECT time.EmpID, time.Date,
SUM(MinutesatState) AS idle FROM time WHERE State = 'idle'
GROUP BY time.EmpID, time.Date;
```

Above query also works

but when I run both queries in the same statement it does not work

```
SELECT time.EmpID, time.Date,
SUM(MinutesatState) AS active FROM time WHERE State = 'active'
SUM(MinutesatState) AS idle FROM time WHERE State = 'idle'
GROUP BY time.EmpID, time.Date;
```

Comment: An SQL `SELECT` query must have only one `FROM` clause and may have zero or one `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last query is syntactically wrong. You cannot use `FROM` clause like that. You are looking for conditional aggregation using `CASE..WHEN` clause(s).

```
SELECT 
  EmpID, 
  Date,
  SUM(CASE WHEN State = 'active' THEN MinutesatState ELSE 0 END) AS active, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN State = 'idle' THEN MinutesatState ELSE 0 END) AS idle
FROM time
GROUP BY EmpID, Date;
```

Comment: This works! 
MIN(StateStarttime) FROM time WHERE EmpID = 303548 and Date = '11-24-2018'

Comment: This works! 
how can i add this to query 
MIN(StateStarttime) FROM time WHERE EmpID = 303548 and Date = '11-24-2018'

Comment: @YatendraRanawat just add MIN(statestarttime) in the select clause

Answer (score 0):

You can include the state in the group by column.

```
SELECT time.EmpID, time.Date,State,
SUM(MinutesatState) As SumOfMinutes FROM time GROUP BY time.EmpID, time.Date,State;
```